# get element id using classname with multiple element with same class name in c#

Tags: c#, dom

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className")== "input-style1 psgn-name")
        {
            textBox10.Text = link.GetAttribute("id");
        }
    }
}
```

result:   i only get id of 4th element id out of 4 element with same class. Now how to get rest of the 3 element id?

Comment: You get all of them but value of textBox10.Text property always replace with new value. Try to debug your code and you'll see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overwriting the text value with each iteration of the loop.

Updated code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className")== "input-style1 psgn-name")
        {
                textBox10.Text += link.GetAttribute("id");
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to say put the first four items found if they exist in to different textboxes then you would need to populate a list and then refer to it like so:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    List<String> results = new List<String>();
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className")== "input-style1 psgn-name")
        {
                results.Add(link.GetAttribute("id"));
        }
    }
    textbox10.Text = results[0];
    textbox11.Text = results[1]; etc....
}
```

Using Linq makes for a more elegant solution:

// Requires using System.Linq

```
String[] results = (from itm in links where itm.GetAttribute("className") == "input-style1 psgn-name" select itm.GetAttribute("id")).ToArray();
```

Then populate your boxes with the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your textbox you overwrite the ID every time. You need to concatenate the string in your textbox. So...

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className")== "input-style1 psgn-name")
        {
            textBox10.Text += link.GetAttribute("id") + ",";
        }
    }

    // Remove last comma
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox10.Text)){
        textBox10.Text = textBox10.Text.Substring(0, textBox10.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Now in your textbox you can see the list of ids of your elements separated by comma.

If you want to set different textbox:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    int i = 10;
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className")== "input-style1 psgn-name")
        {
            foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox){
                    TextBox tb = (CheckBox)c;
                    if(tb.Name == "textBox" + i) {
                        i++;
                        tb.Text = link.GetAttribute("id");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    int i = 10;
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className")== "input-style1 psgn-name")
        {
            TextBox tb = Controls.Find("textBox" + i) as TextBox;
            i++;

            if(tb != null) {
                tb.Text = link.GetAttribute("id");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need different textbox foreach id. If you already have different textbox you can use reflection to get them, otherwise you need to create a textbox in your foreach and then add it to your view

Comment: @RigzinAngchok I updated the code with two solutions